# Complicated Model relationship having difficulty returning data across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

It's the end of the day here, so apologized in advance if what I'm asking doesn't make sense right away.  In Laravel 5.2, we've got a user and client models.  Users can have many clients.  Clients also have all of their data spread out across three or four different tables, and we're using link tables.  To select all the necessary data from all tables for clients, I have a long query that does the joins and selects.  However, I'm trying to use the Eloquent Model for eager loading and having difficulty.

Client model's relationship to user:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function clients() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Clients', 'clientID');
}


public function session()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Session','LNK_SessionClients','ClientID','SessionID');
}

public function sessionClients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Session','LNK_SessionClients','ClientID','SessionID');
}

public function addresses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ClientAddress', 'ClientID');
}

public function phones()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ClientPhone', $this->primaryKey)->where('PhoneNumber', '!=' ,'');
}
public function clientPhoneNumbers() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Client');
}

public function emails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ClientEmail', $this->primaryKey)->where('EmailAddress', '!=' ,'');
}

public function getPhonesListAttribute()
{
    $query = $this->phones()->where('PhoneNumber', '!=', '');
    return ['count' => $query->count(), 'list' => $query->pluck('PhoneNumber')];
}

public function getEmailsListAttribute()
{
    $query = $this->emails()->where('EmailAddress', '!=', '');
    return ['count' => $query->count(), 'list' => $query->pluck('EmailAddress')];
}
```

What I really need:

```
$clients = DB::table('tbl_clients')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_clientphones', 'tbl_clients.clientID', '=', 'tbl_clientphones.ClientId')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_clientemails', 'tbl_clients.clientID', '=', 'tbl_clientemails.ClientId')
        ->leftJoin('lnk_sessionclients', 'tbl_clients.clientID','=','lnk_sessionclients.ClientId')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_sessions','lnk_sessionclients.sessionID', '=', 'tbl_sessions.sessionID')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_users', 'tbl_sessions.userID', '=', 'tbl_users.userID')
        ->leftJoin('lnk_sessionstatus', 'lnk_sessionclients.sessionID', '=', 'lnk_sessionstatus.sessionID')
        ->select('tbl_clients.clientfirstname', 'tbl_clients.clientlastname', 'tbl_clients.createddate', 'tbl_clientphones.phonenumber', 'tbl_clientemails.emailaddress', 'tbl_users.userfirstname', 'tbl_users.userlastname', 'tbl_sessions.movedate', 'lnk_sessionstatus.statusID')
        ->limit(30)
        ->get();
```

ClientController:

```
$clients = Client::query();
    $clients->select('ClientID', 'ClientFirstName', 'ClientLastName', 'createdDate')->where('ClientName', 'LIKE',  "%{$name}%");

    $clients->with(array('sessionClients' => function($query)
    {
        $query->select('UserID','LNK_SessionClients.SessionID');
        $query->select('MoveDate','LNK_SessionClients.SessionID');

        $query->with(array('sources' => function($query)
        {
            $query->select('LKUP_Sources.SourceID','SourceName');
        }));

    }))
    ->has('sessionClients')->has('sessionClients.sources')->limit(10);
```

The Clients controller gets me correct results, but not complete compared to my DB::table() query. I'm having a seemingly impossible time getting the Client Model set up correctly to query the data.  The reason I want to use the Eloquent model is 1)eager loading, 2)pagination, 3)less queries running!  When I execute the code in my controller to return clients, it runs about 50 queries to return five results.  The load time is very bad.

Suggestions?

Updated with full client model relationships.

Comment: Can you add a list of the involved tables and their relevant columns? What other relationships did you define in `Client` (`sessionClients` etc.)?

Comment: What parts of the query are you having problems with? Your controller query is a bit confusing because it contains parts that the original query doesn't (`where('ClientName')`, `has('sessionClients')` etc.).